# Avoid duplicates while creating CSV file

Tags: c#, duplicates, export-to-csv

So this is the part of the code that I need to modify. I need to make it so that there wouldn't be any duplicates but also in the file on second column should create a number how many times it has been found as a duplicate. It should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xqci.jpg

```
private static void SaveDataToFile(List<Ring> rings)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Metalai.csv"))
    {
        List<Ring> results = new List<Ring>();
        writer.WriteLine("Metalai");

        foreach (var ring in rings)
            if (!results.Contains(ring))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("{0}", ring.Metalas);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use linq group by and count elements in each group

Comment: How would that look like exacly? Im fairly new to C# so I'm not that good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labas draugas, I think you are looking for something like this,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Ring> rings = new List<Ring>();
    rings.Add(new Ring { Id = 1, Name = "siauliai", Metalas = "s" });
    rings.Add(new Ring { Id = 2, Name = "kaunas", Metalas = "k" });
    rings.Add(new Ring { Id = 3, Name = "vilnius", Metalas = "v" });
    rings.Add(new Ring { Id = 4, Name = "klapedia", Metalas = "ka" });
    rings.Add(new Ring { Id = 5, Name = "siauliai", Metalas = "s" });

    SaveDataToFile(rings);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void SaveDataToFile(List<Ring> rings)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Metalai.csv"))
    {
        List<string> ringMetalas = new List<string>();
        writer.WriteLine("Metalai;Duplication");

        foreach (var ring in rings)
        {
            if (!ringMetalas.Contains(ring.Metalas))
            {
                var duplicationCount = rings.Count(r => r.Metalas == ring.Metalas);
                ringMetalas.Add(ring.Metalas);

                var mesage = $"{ring.Metalas}";
                if (duplicationCount > 1)
                    mesage += $";{duplicationCount}";

                writer.WriteLine("{0}", mesage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result Like;

```
Metalai Duplication
s       2
k   
v   
ka
```

Hope its help to you

Comment: Oho dekui! *Bows down* :3

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `HashSet<Ring>` instead because it's much more efficient. You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Ring` and/or implement `IEquatable<Ring>`.

However, you can also use this simple approach:

```
private static void SaveDataToFile(List<Ring> rings)
{
    var metalasLookup = rings.ToLookup(r => r.Metalas);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Metalai.csv"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Metalai");
        foreach (var metalasGroups in metalasLookup)
        {
            int count = metalasGroups.Count();
            string = line $"{metalasGroups.Key},{(count == 0 ? "" : count.ToString())}";
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

or with a very concise version:

```
static void SaveDataToFile(List<Ring> rings)
{
    var lines = rings.ToLookup(r => r.Metalas).Select(x => $"{x.Key},{(x.Any() ? x.Count().ToString() : "")}");
    File.WriteAllLines(@"Metalai.csv", lines);
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. What it should look like is to delete the duplicates but also on the next collumn show how many times it has duplicated. Here's a picture how it should look like: https://imgur.com/a/KpUbf

Answer (score 1):

Now really...

```
if(!results.Contains(ring)){
    results.Add(ring);
    writer....
} else {
    duplicates++;
}
```

where 'duplicates' would be your counter counting duplicates. Start it from 0.

Comment: But will that show a number next to the duplicate in .csv file?

Comment: Also the file is still showing duplicates so nothing changed.

Comment: @RenatasKarnauskas "But will that show a number next to the duplicate in .csv file?" - no, it will not, it just shows the total number of duplicates. Sorry, misunderstood your need

Comment: @RenatasKarnauskas "Also the file is still showing duplicates so nothing changed." - List.Contains relies on the Equals method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks )

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want Ring to implement Equals() and have a decent GetHashCode(). Then use a Dictionary where the value is count. It's not fancy, but its clear.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sorting rings before you start creating your csv-file to lower the computational effort. In the sorted case you know that duplicates would show up next to each other, thus, when writing rings(15) you only have to verify that rings(14) is no duplicate. Otherwise you would need to go through the whole rings variable ech and every time which increases the effort.

So for the sorted case this could be a solution:

```
private static void SaveDataToFile(List<Ring> rings)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Metalai.csv"))
    {
        List<Ring> results = new List<Ring>();
        writer.WriteLine("Metalai");
        String oldRing = String.empty;
        int duplicates = 0;
        foreach (var ring in rings)
            if (!results.Contains(ring))
        {
            if (ring.Metalas == oldRing)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", ring.Metalas);
                duplicates++;
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteLine("{0}", ring.Metalas);
                oldRing = ring.Metalas;
            }
        }
    }
}
```